# Can $x$ be defined without itself when $\frac{p^{x}}{x} = c$?

Tags: exponential-function

If the equation is

$$\frac{p^{x}}{x} = c$$

where $p$ and $c$ are constants.

then find $x$.

Comment: What are $p,c$ and $x$ ?

Comment: @HarshKumar p and c are both constants. x is the variable.

Comment: Using Lambert $W$ function, $$x=-\frac{1}{\ln p} W\left( -\frac{\ln p}{c} \right)$$

Comment: Try to remember (since you will need it quite many times) that any equation which can write or rewriye $A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$ has solutions(s) in terms of Lambert function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not exist an elementary closed form solution. However, one can express it in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

> By definition, the Lambert W function is the inverse of:
>   $$f(z)=ze^z \tag{1}$$

---

Firstly, we use the identity $p^x\equiv e^{\ln{p}\cdot x}$. This gives:
$$\frac{1}{x}\cdot e^{\ln{p}\cdot x}=c$$
Now, let's substitute $u=-\ln{p}\cdot x$. Therefore:
$$-\frac{\ln{p}}{u}\cdot e^{-u}=c$$
After some algebraic manipulation, we obtain:
$$ue^u=-\frac{\ln{p}}{c}$$
Now, we may use the definition given on $(1)$.
Thus, we obtain:
$$u=W\left(-\frac{\ln{p}}{c}\right)$$
Substituting back for $u$ gives an explicit solution for $x$.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks to Lambert and You.